# Why are my connections not returning to the pool with Hikari?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

We have this database layer with `JdbcTemplate`:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    protected SomeObj  insert(SomeObj obj) {
        this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(INSERT_QUERY, MyJdbcUtils.prepareQueryParams(obj));
        synchronized (obj.getSomeList()) { decidable.getReasons().forEach(someItem -> { if (someItem != null) getJdbcTemplate().update(INSERT_ITEM_QUERY, obj.getId(), someItem ); }); }
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public SomeObj update(SomeObj obj) {
        this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(UPDATE_QUERY, MyJdbcUtils.prepareQueryParams(obj));
        synchronized (obj.getSomeList()) { decidable.getReasons().forEach(someItem -> { if (someItem != null) getJdbcTemplate().update(UPDATE_ITEM_QUERY, obj.getId(), someItem ); }); }
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public SomeObj upsert(SomeObj obj) {

        try {
            return this.insert(obj);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException exception) {
            final SomeObj existingObj = this.find(obj.getSomeId()).get(0);
            // Populate some fields from existing object
        }

        return this.update(transaction);

    }
```

MyJdbcUtils is as follows:

```
public static Map<String, ?> prepareQueryParams(SomeObj obj) {
        return new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("someColumn", obj.getSomeColumn());
            ...
        }};
    }
```

My database related `application.properties` are as follows:

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.leakDetectionThreshold=5000
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=100
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=20
spring.datasource.idleTimeout=30000
```

After a while, Hikari pool logs looks like this:

```
HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=100, active=100, idle=0, waiting=2)
```

with a lot of:

```
Connection leak detection triggered for org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@17b19afa on thread http-nio-8080-exec-100, stack trace follows

java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar!/:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:184) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.company.project.core.domain.transaction.JdbcTransactionDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87fab16e.update(<generated>) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.company.project.core.integration.spring.TransactionIntegrationConfiguration.asyncPersistenceService(TransactionIntegrationConfiguration.java:208) ~[classes!/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor326.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:508) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:478) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$Invoker.get(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:1012) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:341) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:451) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.processTransaction(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.company.project.core.services.transaction.TransactionServiceImpl.async(TransactionServiceImpl.java:101) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.company.project.core.services.transaction.TransactionServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$73b9cf27.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.company.project.core.services.transaction.TransactionServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eae305f2.async(<generated>) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.company.project.core.controllers.TransactionController.async(TransactionController.java:52) ~[classes!/:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor323.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

until:

```
HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms
```

DBA confirms that the longest query is ~1second and I'm sure that the queries should run around that long. What am I doing wrong? Why aren't my connections returning to the pool and are still marked as active?

**Update:**

As per comments, I switched the logic to:

```
private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

@Autowired
public MyDao (PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, DataSource dataSource) {
    setDataSource(dataSource); // Class extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport
    this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
}

@Override
protected SomeObj  insert(SomeObj obj) {
    return this.transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
        this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(INSERT_QUERY, MyJdbcUtils.prepareQueryParams(obj));
        for (String someItem : obj.getSomeList()) if (someItem != null) getJdbcTemplate().update(INSERT_ITEM_QUERY, obj.getId(), someItem );
        return obj;
    });        
}

@Override
public SomeObj update(SomeObj obj) {
    return this.transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
        this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(UPDATE_QUERY, MyJdbcUtils.prepareQueryParams(obj));
        for (String someItem : obj.getSomeList()) if (someItem != null) getJdbcTemplate().update(UPDATE_ITEM_QUERY, obj.getId(), someItem ); 
        return obj;
    });
}
```

However the issue did not resolve.

Comment: double check out that Hikari is configured as connection pool, and not simply as factory, AFAIK we've got once sth similar, when no max size was set

Comment: We do have `HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=100, active=100, idle=0, waiting=2)` in logs so I'm assuming I do have a pool.

Comment: `MyJdbcUtils.prepareQueryParams(obj)` this looks sketchy and your `@Transactional doesn't work either (as it is an internal method call). Your syncronized is also weird why is that even there and I doubt it will even work as i doubt the same list will be used for each call. Finally please add **the full stacktrace** and not just a snippet of the 5 top lines. Looking again your configuration combined with the statistics don't make sense... You set 10 as the max, the statistics report 100.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. Updated the question with complete stack trace, fixed 10/100 typo, and expanded the `MyJdbcUtils` class. But `@Transactional` works as intended, i.e. when I intentionally fail the second query in the database layer, the first one rolls back as well.

Comment: Thanks for the updated stacktrace, I see hibernate is in use, please add your JPA properties/configuration.

Comment: It might work as intended but not through those `@Transactional` annotations. So there is something else driving the transactions. But please add the JPA configuration as well. ALso max of 10 with a minimum of 100? I suspect you wanted that to be the other way around. I don't see the `MyJdbcUtils` in your question?

Comment: The moment I remove `@Transactional` on the methods, although the second query fails, the first one succeeds, so I assumed it is `@Transactional` annotations that made it work. As for JPA, I have nothing else in terms of configuration for JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: As @M.Deinum explained the syncronized is weird why is that even there? The synchronized in case of lock will cost more time, it should be outside the `@Transactional`. Try putting the synchronized in the component calling `insert(SomeObj obj)` and `update(SomeObj obj)`

Comment: There must be something JPA related in your configuration, as the `HibernateJpaDialect` is in use. Your current question doesn't show anything related to your JPA setup, I would expect at least something in there. Regarding the `@Transactional` I assume you are calling the `upsert` method, from the `upsert` method it doesn't work. So you must be calling the method from somewhere else. My assumption is/was that you are calling the `upsert` method. With regards to the `syncronized` (and the comment on that) I doubt it will even work when you pull it up a level.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right, I'm using `upsert` method, and it's strange that it works calling from the same class, as it would not proxy via the annotation. However, would getting rid of `synchronized` and switching to `TransactionTemplate` help?

Comment: Unless you enabled AspectJ and load- or compile time weaving? Replacing `syncronized` with `TransactionTemplate` won't change a thing, the `syncronized` doesn't really add anything but time from a technical and function pov it doesn't add anything. Are you doing a `getConnection` anywhere in your codebase? The fact that you get the error at that place doesn't mean the leak is there (it is only detected there).

Comment: I've completely got rid of `synchronized` and replaced `@Transactional` with `TransactionTemplate`, not `synchronized` with `TransactionTemplate`.

Comment: If your maximum pool size is 10 `spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=10` how can you have 100 as idle `spring.datasource.minimumIdle=100` 
try changing the minimumIdle to something smaller

Comment: @bhantol Sorry that was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: I would consider switching to aspectj aop.  Read these: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-vs-aspectj and https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop

Comment: @M.Deinum Updated the code/question with `TransactionTemplate` to no luck.

Comment: If the leak is in your code (and it probably is) changing the way to manage transactions doesn't solve it. As you still have the same leak. I also mentioned already that you get a warning here it doesn't mean the leak is here! As mentioned check your code for usages of the connection.

Comment: It's only called in a single place and only with a simple `@RestController` call.